# MAAS and openstack

Tags: cloud-computing, cloud-hosting, openstack

I am confused how MAAS (Metal as a service) is different from Cloud? What is the difference or similarities between MAAS and openstack, are they both same or different

Comment: A quick search would have given you this: http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1103 Downvoting because you did not do ANY research before asking the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[MAAS](http://maas.ubuntu.com/) is just a provisioning approach that operates in units of physical servers rather than virtual machines. It's also a terrible acronym.

[Openstack](http://www.openstack.org/) is a cloud computing management platform. In this context, you'd use MAAS to build the foundation for a cloud solution like Openstack.

Are you building a cloud service?

Comment: Not right now. Someday :)